# Define abbrev for `helm-mini`

Tags: helm, abbrev

I am trying to define an abbreviation for `helm-mini`, I would like `d` to expand to `*dired`. When I try my usual way of `*dired` `C-x a i l`, I get an error saying `Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer`.

Comment: Setting or binding `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-nil will let you bypass that error. Whether that's what you need here or should use, I don't know.

Comment: Changed comment to an answer (comments can be deleted anytime).

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. The abbrev is getting defined for a fundamental mode, does this mean that the minibuffer is of fundamental mode? Is it possible to restrict this only to buffers created by `helm-mini`?

Comment: Please post a followup question as a separate question. And provide a recipe or otherwise make clear just what you mean. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Setting or binding `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil` will let you bypass that error. Whether that's what you need here or should use, I don't know.